# For which partial orders is the Axiom of Choice necessary to prove the existence of ultrafilters?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

This question is about [ultrafilters on partial orders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafilter#Ultrafilters_on_partial_orders). Using the Axiom of Choice, one may prove that every partial order has an ultrafilter on it. For certain partial orders, some form of AC is known to be necessary, but for other partial orders this is not so:

*Example 1*: (ZF) If $P$ is atomic, then it has an ultrafilter.

*Example 2*: (ZF) If $P = \omega^{<\omega}$ is the set of all finite sequences of integers, ordered by extension, then it has an ultrafilter. Any $r \in \omega^\omega$ can be used to define an ultrafilter on $P$, namely the set of all finite initial subsequences of $r$.

> > My question is whether we can determine that the statement "there exists an ultrafilter on $P$'' is independent of ZF just by looking at the combinatorial properties of $P$ (without needing to go through a forcing argument to construct a symmetric model).

I don't expect an exact characterization. But I would love to know a reasonably general sufficient condition for implying that ZF is not strong enough to prove the existence of an ultrafilter on $P$.

**My motivating example:**

Let $P$ be the set of all dense subsets of $\mathbb R$, ordered by inclusion. I came across this partial order recently while thinking about a problem in topology, and I'd like to know whether ZF alone proves that this partial order admits an ultrafilter.

I strongly suspect that the answer is no (though I have not yet tried to work out the details). Right now, the only way I know to approach the problem is to build a symmetric model of ZF. It seems to me that it should be possible, somehow, to know beforehand, just by looking at $P$, that something beyond ZF is needed to get an ultrafilter.

**A caveat:**

In my question above, we should think of $P$ as the unique partial order satisfying some definition. In particular, I want to allow that $P^M$ and $P^N$ can be two different sets if $M$ and $N$ are two different models of set theory. (For example, the phrase "the dense subsets of $\mathbb R$, ordered by inclusion" defines a partial order, but the set satisfying this definition can be made larger by forcing.)

This point is perhaps pedantic, but also pertinent. To see why, suppose $P$ is a partial order in some model $M$ of ZFC, and suppose $N \supseteq M$ is a model of ZF. Then $P \in N$, $P$ is a partial order in $N$, and, *no matter what*, $P$ has an ultrafilter in $N$. The proof is easy: fix $U \in M$ such that $M \models$ "$U$ is an ultrafilter on $P$'' and then observe that the statement "$U$ is an ultrafilter on $P$'' is absolute to larger models of set theory.

*Example 3*: (ZF) If $P$ is a constructible partial order (i.e., if $P \in L$) then $P$ has an ultrafilter. In fact, any $U \in L$ such that $L \models$ "$U$ is an ultrafilter on $P$" is an ultrafilter on $P$.

Comment: Have you looked at Herrlich's book, The Axiom of Choice?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Yes, a bit, but I can't seem to find any theorems of this kind in there. He mentions at the top of page 58 that some partial orders have ultrafilters on them in ZF, but there seems to be no attempt to characterize those partial orders.

Comment: A sufficient criterion:  if the set of nodes of $P$ is well-orderable, then it has an ultrafilter. This generalizes your example 3.